# Return bool value in pythonic way comparing within list?

Tags: python, boolean

I am comparing fist element of list vs all the elements of list. If False is there I need to return false or if all are true, I need to return True. Currently I am doing this with `if-else`. is there any pythonic way to return `bool` value

```
def checker(inp):
    _compare = [ _==inp[0] for _ in inp] 
    return False if False in _compare else True

lst = [5, 5, 5]
lst2 = [5, 5, 6]

# Case 1
level = checker(inp=lst)
print(level)
True

# Case 2 
level2 = checker(inp=lst2)
print(level2)
False
```

Any pythonic way to achieve this

```
return False if False in _compare else True
```

Comment: just `False in _compare`

Comment: Try to state your problem in a more simple manner: you want to figure out whether all items in the list are the same, whether the list is homogeneous?

Comment: Yes @deceze if all the numbers in list are same I want to return True if not False

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if all the numbers in list are same I want to return True if not False

The most straight forward way:

```
return len(set(inp)) == 1
```

This does require the values to be hashable, but simple numbers are.

Answer (score 2):

`False in _compare` is already a boolean so

```
return False not in _compare
```

is the best way to do it.

but looking wider:

```
_==inp[0] for _ in inp
```

should be

```
return all(x==inp[0] for x in inp)
```

so it returns `False` if one value is `False`

This solution works even if the items aren't hashable.

Comment: `return False in _compare` gives me opposite of bool value. Case 1 returns False and Case 2 returns True

Comment: `False not in _compare` then…

Comment: yup thanks i wasn't sure that double negation didn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is identical to the question "I need to check if all elements in my list are identical", since both are true for exactly the same cases. So you could also solve it like this:

```
def checker(inp):
    return len(set(inp)) == 1
```

If that is the most pythonic way to go about it .. I don't know.

edit: alternative in case of unhashable items:

```
def checker(inp):
    return not [True for i in range(len(inp) - 1)) if [inp[i] != inp[i+1]]
```

Comment: You are assuming the list items are hashable.

Comment: @chepner washable, you could have convinced me that was a real term, it might catch on

Comment: Stupid autocorrect ;)

Comment: @chepner Alternative added. Comments on pythonicity? =)

Comment: `any(inp[i] != inp[i+1] for i in range(len(inp) - 1))` would simpler, but I'd choose https://stackoverflow.com/a/47553635/1126841 over this.